# Rails: Why is only one email sent to the last member of a loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very much a rails novice!

I am trying to write a method for a kind of on-line committee meeting.  There are a fixed number(9) of users. When a user proposes a topic for discussion and/or voting the submit button needs to send an email to all members.

in   app/mailers/user_mailer.rb I have:-

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def new_topic_alert(topic)
    @users = User.all
    @users.each do |user|
      mail to: user.email, subject: "New topic alert"
    end
  end
end
```

as part of app/controllers/topics_controller.rb I have:-

```
def send_alert
  @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)
  UserMailer.new_topic_alert(@topic).deliver_now
end
```

and:-

```
def create
  @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)
  if @topic.save
    send_alert
    flash[:info] = "New Topic alert emails sent."
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Please, why does the loop in user_mailer only send an email to the final person of the list.  By incorporating "byebug" I have shown that it goes through all the user emails.

Comment: `mail to: @users.map(&:email), subject: "New topic alert"` - read description of `to` option [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/Base/mail).

Comment: if you want to send the same email to a bunch of emails, pass to `to:` an array of emails, so, instead of the `@users.each` loop you have there, do something like `emails = @users.map(&:email)`, and then `mail to: emails, subject: "New topic alert"`

Comment: or `emails = User.pluck(:email)` then `mail to: emails`

Answer (score 1):

Try like below:

```
def send_alert
  @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)
  users = User.all
  users.each do |u|
    UserMailer.new_topic_alert(@topic, u).deliver_now
  end
end
```

and update the mailer like

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def new_topic_alert(topic,user)
    mail to: user.email, subject: "New topic alert"
  end
end
```

Comment: there's a better way if he/she wants to send the same email to a bunch of emails, look at my comment in his post.

Comment: correct, I agree but I just try to use his scenerio & this will also work

Comment: Thanks all for your helpful answers. Chakreshwar Sharma's has worked fine.  I'll work through the other 2 later, as a learning exercise.  I would appreciate an answer to why mine didn't work

Comment: This is because you are writing the same statement in the loop,   mail to: user.email, subject: "New topic alert"  & when it takes the last user when the loop ends

Comment: for eg a= 30
a =20 puts a , then it will print 20 as the last value of a is 20